# Using setup.py for cross platform deployment

Tags: python, numpy, conda, setup.py

I'm developing a Python app under Win10 which will be deployed on Linux under a Conda environment.

Let's say that the only package that I explicitly import is `Numpy`. What must I put into the `setup.py` and `environment.yaml` files so that

The required dependencies (including C compiler) are automatically installed under Linux when I run:

```
conda env create --force -n environment.yaml
```

My goal is to use a CI tool like Gitlabs/AWSCodePipeline to automatically build this and run tests when I make a change to the code under Win10

Answer (score 0):

There's `install_requires` keywrod to pass to `setup` function, and you should put there `numpy` and add to this line some version specificators. For example,  `install_requires=['numpy>=1.0']`

More about specificators and other options you can read [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide)

Comment: Will this be sufficient when I try to deploy to Linux? Won't it complain about needing a C compiler? I want to know if there is a way to delegate that decision to the environment manager in Linux

Comment: it highly depends if you allow to install pre-build libraries or force build, if a numpy build exists for this environment and python version and yes, if build is possible. If you're forced to build from source for some reason, you need python headers, c and c++ compilers. Please, also consult with build instructions for individual packages. Some of them require external libraries and, sometimes, additional compilers. Requirements for Numpy are located [here](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/building/linux.html)